# PHP - Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found (LEMP/PHP7)

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, pecl, fpm

Note: Other questions about this error address it for Windows, LAMP installs, and PHP5. This is a LEMP stack with PHP7.0.

I'm trying to use mongodb for the first time in PHP but I get `Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found` with the following code:

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
```

I'm running PHP7.0-FPM and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04. I also have PHP5.4-FPM installed on the same server but I'm trying to use mongodb with PHP7.0-FPM. I have installed the package `php-mongodb` as well as the pecl package `mongodb` and added `extension=mongo.so` to php.ini but it's not working. If I run `locate mongo.so` I see it's at `/usr/lib/php/20131226/mongo.so`. Not sure what to try from here.

Output of `php -m | grep -i mongo`:

```
mongodb
```

Output of `php -i | grep mongo`:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
libmongoc bundled version => 1.5.5
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => enabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Comment: Did you restart nginx

Comment: I reloaded PHP7.0-FPM. Will try nginx as well.

Comment: Just did `systemctl reload nginx` and `systemctl reload php7.0-fpm` but still same.

Comment: Just did a restart on both as well and still same.

Comment: what is the output of `php -m | grep -i mongo` and `php -i | grep mongo`. Please add those to the question

Comment: Added to question.